# Summarize specific word in data table in R

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Domain" = c("Euka"),
  "Kingdom" = c("An","Plan"),
  "Division" = c("20181121","20181128","20181203"),
  "Species" = c("20181115_AG25_MAGH_50_A05_CGT.TXT","20181122_AG25_MAGH_50_C05_CGT.ARR",
                "20181115_AG25_MAGH_50_G05_CGT.TXT","20181124_AG25_MAGH_50_G45_CGT.TXT",
                "20181204_AG25_MAGH_50_G05_CGT.ARR","20181205_AG25_MAGH_50_G45_CGT.TXT",
                "20181207_AG25_MAGH_50_T05_CGT.ARR","20181215_AG25_MAGH_50_F45_CGT.TXT",
                "20181223_AG25_MAGH_50_R07_CGT.GGI","20181225_TW77_MAGH_33_L06_CGT.ARR",
                "20181226_TW77_MAGH_33_S07_CGT.ARR","20181227_TW77_MAGH_33_C06_CGT.TXT")
)
```

I want summarize that

| Division | 20181121 | 20181128 | 20181203 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total_TXT | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| Total_ARR | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| Total_GGI | 0 | 0 | 1 |

How can I achieve this in R?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option, where we use `count` to get the total for each group, then we can put it into a wide format with `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(gr = Division) %>% 
  count(Division = str_replace_all(Species, '.*\\.', '')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "gr", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(Division = paste0("Total_", Division))
```

**Output**

```
  Division  `20181121` `20181128` `20181203`
  <chr>          <int>      <int>      <int>
1 Total_ARR          2          3          0
2 Total_TXT          2          1          3
3 Total_GGI          0          0          1
```

Or here is a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)

df <-
  setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(cn = Division, Division = str_replace_all(Species, '.*\\.', ''))]

dcast(df,
      paste0("Total_", Division) ~ cn,
      value.var = "N",
      fill = 0)
```

Comment: If Division hv "NA" , in First way(tidyverse)  still can work? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @FenNei If `Division` has an `NA`, it would still work, but it would create another column for `NA`s. But if the value for the `NA` is in the dataframe, then it could be filled prior to doing the count.

Answer (score 0):

We need to extract the last three characters from Species:

```
x <- nchar(df$Species)
rowlbl <- substr(df$Species, x-2, x)
table(rowlbl, df$Division)
# rowlbl 20181121 20181128 20181203
#    ARR        2        3        0
#    GGI        0        0        1
#    TXT        2        1        3
```

Comment: Could I ask about setting -2 this reason?

Comment: last three characters are nchar(df$Species) = 33 for your data, 32, and 31 so we want to take characters 31 to 33.

Answer (score 0):

Base R one-liner -

```
table(sub('.*\\.', '', df$Species), df$Division)

#     20181121 20181128 20181203
#  ARR        2        3        0
#  GGI        0        0        1
#  TXT        2        1        3
```

**Explanation :**

`sub` removes everything until the last `"."` returning

```
sub('.*\\.', '', df$Species)
#[1] "TXT" "ARR" "TXT" "TXT" "ARR" "TXT" "ARR" "TXT" "GGI" "ARR" "ARR" "TXT"
```

This is then used in `table` with `Division` values.

---

`sub` can also be replaced with `tools::file_ext` for a non-regex approach.

```
table(tools::file_ext(df$Species), df$Division)
```